# Generate Protobuf documentation?

Tags: documentation, protocols, protocol-buffers, documentation-generation

Does anyone know of a good tool to generate Google Protobuf documentation using the .proto source files?

Comment: Last time I checked (which was admittedly a while ago), the "protoc" tool doesn't keep any of the comments, so anything based on using the serialized descriptors would be hard - it would probably have to be a custom parser.

Comment: look at this thread http://www.mail-archive.com/protobuf@googlegroups.com/msg02830.html

Answer (score 17):

[**Update**: Aug 2017. Adapted to the full Go rewrite of protoc-gen-bug, currently `1.0.0-rc`]

The `protoc-doc-gen`, created by @estan (see also [his earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400484/8295283)) provides a good and easy way to generate your documentation in html, json, markdown, pdf and other formats.

There are number of additional things that I should mention:

1. [estan](https://github.com/estan) is no longer the maintainer of `protoc-doc-gen`, but [pseudomuto](https://github.com/pseudomuto) is
2. In contrast to what I've read on various pages it *is* possible to use rich inline formatting (bold/italic, links, code snippets, etc.) within comments
3. `protoc-gen-doc` has been completely rewritten in Go and now uses Docker for generation (instead of `apt-get`)

The repository is now here: https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc

To demonstrate the second point I have created an example repository to auto-generate the [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) Hypercore Protocol documentation in a nice format.

You can view various `html` and `markdown` output generation options at (or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295215/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-type-alias-in-protobuf-proto2/45254099#45254099) for a markdown example on SO):

- https://github.com/aschrijver/protoc-gen-doc-example

The [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) script that does all the automation is this simple `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

language: bash

before_script:
  # Create directory structure, copy files
  - mkdir build && mkdir build/html
  - cp docgen/stylesheet.css build/html

script:
  # Create all flavours of output formats to test (see README)
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build:/out -v $(pwd)/schemas/html:/protos:ro pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build/html:/out -v $(pwd)/schemas/html:/protos:ro -v $(pwd)/docgen:/templates:ro pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc --doc_opt=/templates/custom-html.tmpl,inline-html-comments.html protos/HypercoreSpecV1_html.proto
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build:/out -v $(pwd)/schemas/md:/protos:ro pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc --doc_opt=markdown,hypercore-protocol.md
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build:/out -v $(pwd)/schemas/md:/protos:ro -v $(pwd)/docgen:/templates:ro pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc --doc_opt=/templates/custom-markdown.tmpl,hypercore-protocol_custom-template.md protos/HypercoreSpecV1_md.proto

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true          # Do not forget, or the whole gh-pages branch is cleaned
  name: datproject            # Name of the committer in gh-pages branch
  local_dir: build            # Take files from the 'build' output directory
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard (see README)
  on:
    all_branches: true        # Could be set to 'branch: master' in production
```

(**PS**: *The [hypercore](https://github.com/mafintosh/hypercore) protocol is one of the core specifications of the [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) ecosystem of modules for creating decentralized peer-to-peer applications. I used their `.proto` file to demonstrate concepts*)

Answer (score 11):

An open source protobuf plugin that generates DocBook and PDF from the proto files.

http://code.google.com/p/protoc-gen-docbook/

Disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin.

Comment: to be a little pedantic :) I'd say "disclosure" not "disclaimer"

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the askldjd's answer, I'd like to point out my own tool at https://github.com/estan/protoc-gen-doc . It is also a protocol buffer compiler plugin, but can generate HTML, MarkDown or DocBook out of the box. It can also be customized using Mustache templates to generate any text based format you like.

Documentation comments are written using `/** ... */` or `/// ...`.

Answer (score 10):

In Protobuf 2.5 the "//" comments you put into your .proto files actually makes it into the generated java source code as Javadoc comments. More specifically the protoc compiler will take your "//" comments like this:

```
// 
// Message level comments
message myMsg {

    // Field level comments
    required string name=1;
}
```

will go into your generated java source files. For some reason protoc encloses the Javadoc comments in `<pre>` tags.  But all in all it is a nice new feature in v2.5.

Answer (score 6):

Doxygen supports so called input filters, which allow you to transform code into something doxygen understands. Writing such a filter for transforming the Protobuf IDL into C++ code (for example) would allow you to use the full power of Doxygen in .proto files. See item 12 of the [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html).

I did something similar for CMake, the input filter just transforms CMake macros and functions to C function declarations. You can find it [here](https://github.com/saschazelzer/CMakeDoxygenFilter/).

Answer (score 6):

The thread is old, but the question still seems relevant. I have had very good results with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) + [proto2cpp](http://sourceforge.net/p/proto2cpp/wiki/Home/). proto2cpp works as an input filter for doxygen.

Comment: I can't get the example provided in the download file to work with Doxygen v1.8.9.1 and proto2cpp v0.5-beta. If i open the file `html/index.html` I can not see any documentation. I've enabled logging and pasted the output of the generated `proto2cpp.log` file [here](http://pastebin.com/hkVYNPhM). Did something change regarding filtering in Doxygen? Do you know how-to fix it? Or do I have wrong expectations regarding this project?

Comment: It's working as expected with v1.8.1.1, though I cannot find fundamental changes regarding input filtering in the CHANGELOG of "Doxgen".

Answer (score 3):

Since the .proto file is mostly just declaration, I usually find that the source file with inline comments is straightforward and effective documentation.

Comment: The .proto file is effective documentation for developers only. It may be not suitable for less technical staff.

Answer (score -5):

https://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html

> Self-describing Messages
>
> Protocol Buffers do not contain descriptions of their own types. Thus,
>   given only a raw message without the corresponding .proto file
>   defining its type, it is difficult to extract any useful data.
>
> However, note that the contents of a .proto file can itself be
>   represented using protocol buffers. The file
>   src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto in the source code package
>   defines the message types involved. protoc can output a
>   FileDescriptorSet – which represents a set of .proto files – using the
>   --descriptor_set_out option. With this, you could define a
>   self-describing protocol message like so:
>
> message SelfDescribingMessage {   // Set of .proto files which define
>   the type.   required FileDescriptorSet proto_files = 1;
>
> // Name of the message type.  Must be defined by one of the files in
>   // proto_files.   required string type_name = 2;
>
> // The message data.   required bytes message_data = 3; }
>
> By using classes like DynamicMessage (available in C++ and Java), you
>   can then write tools which can manipulate SelfDescribingMessages.
>
> All that said, the reason that this functionality is not included in
>   the Protocol Buffer library is because we have never had a use for it
>   inside Google.

Comment: This is about transferring the data type definition along with the actual data, it doesn't say anything about documentation.