# Is there a way to create a type alias in protobuf (proto2)?

Tags: documentation, protocols, protocol-buffers, documentation-generation

Is it possible to create aliases of protobuf's scalar types?

For example, I'd like to use `Sequence` in lieu of `string`, even though they would be binary equivalent.

My immediate goal is to make documentation (generated with protoc-gen-doc) more readily understandable.

Ideally, this type would be represented in languages that support type checking, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this will be a bit dull answer but:

No, I'm not aware of such feature existing or having been planned.

You can sort of emulate it by making submessages that contain only a single field, but that will alter the binary representation.

You're not the first asking this though:

- [Re: [protobuf] does protoc allow you to typedef a scalar ?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/protobuf/uvcQc43-_r0/aVdi1uI6lI0J)
- [Is it possible to define an alias for type (enum or message) in google protobuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533549/is-it-possible-to-define-an-alias-for-type-enum-or-message-in-google-protobuf)

Comment: Have they explained why not? Coming from ASN.1, this was the first feature I tried using. Would make things much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

[**Update**: Aug 2017. Adapted to the full Go rewrite of protoc-gen-bug, currently `1.0.0-rc`]

I don't have an answer for type aliases, but do have one for this:

> My immediate goal is to make documentation (generated with [`protoc-gen-doc`](https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc)) more readily understandable.

And also I want to point out that `protoc-gen-doc` has been entirely rewritten in Go and now uses Docker for generation instead of `apt-get`.

I have created some `html` and `markdown` demo's of using inline rich formatting within your comments, like adding links, code snippets, tables, bold, italic, etc.

And also describe how you can *auto-generate and publish to Github Pages (`gh-pages` branch) using [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/)*

There are some small bugs that still need to be solved (Aug 2017) for it to be production-ready.

View the demo's + description at:

- https://github.com/aschrijver/protoc-gen-doc-example

.

For example having **markdown inlined comments like these**:

````
/**
* The **SLEEP** format is designed by the [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) 
* to allow for sparse replication, meaning you can efficiently download
* only the metadata and data required to resolve a single byte region 
* of a single file, which makes Dat suitable for a wide variety of streaming,
* _real-time_ and large dataset use cases.
*
* To take advantage of this, Dat includes a _network protocol_. It is message
* based and stateless, making it possible to implement on a variety of network
* transport protocols including UDP and TCP.
*
* Both metadata and content registers in **SLEEP** share the exact same
* replication protocol.
*
* Individual messages are encoded using Protocol Buffers and there are ten
* message types in total.
*
* ### Wire Protocol
*
* Over the wire messages are packed in the following lightweight
* container format:
*
* ```
* <varint - length of rest of message>
*   <varint - header>
*   <message>
* ```
*
* The `header` value is a single `varint` that has two pieces of information,
* the integer type that declares a 4-bit message type (used below), and a
* channel identifier, 0 for metadata and 1 for content.
*
* To generate this varint, you bitshift the 4-bit type integer onto the end of
* the channel identifier, e.g. channel << 4 | <4-bit-type>.
*
* ### Using in NodeJS
*
* The `protocol-bufers` package offers an intuitive javascript API, so you need
* not worry about low-level protocol concepts.
* 
* This example demonstrates how you create a feed and start streaming:
*
* ```javascript
*   var protocol = require('hypercore-protocol')
*   var stream = protocol()
*   
*   // open a feed specified by a 32 byte key
*   var feed = stream.feed(Buffer('deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef'))
*   
*   feed.request({block: 42})
*   feed.on('data', function (message) {
*     console.log(message) // contains message.index and message.value
*   })
*   
*   stream.pipe(anotherStream).pipe(stream)
* ```
*/
````

.

Will result in **output similar to this**:

---

> ### HypercoreSpecV1_md.proto
>
> The **SLEEP** format is designed by the [Dat
>   Project](https://datproject.org) to allow for sparse replication,
>   meaning you can efficiently download only the metadata and data
>   required to resolve a single byte region of a single file, which makes
>   Dat suitable for a wide variety of streaming,
>   *real-time* and large dataset use cases.
>
> To take advantage of this, Dat includes a *network protocol*. It is
>   message based and stateless, making it possible to implement on a
>   variety of network transport protocols including UDP and TCP.
>
> Both metadata and content registers in **SLEEP** share the exact same
>   replication protocol.
>
> Individual messages are encoded using Protocol Buffers and there are
>   ten message types in total.
>
> #### Wire Protocol
>
> Over the wire messages are packed in the following lightweight
>   container format:
>
> ```
> <varint - length of rest of message>
>   <varint - header>
>   <message>
> ```
>
> The `header` value is a single `varint` that has two pieces of
>   information, the integer type that declares a 4-bit message type (used
>   below), and a channel identifier, 0 for metadata and 1 for content.
>
> To generate this varint, you bitshift the 4-bit type integer onto the
>   end of the channel identifier, e.g. channel << 4 | <4-bit-type>.
>
> #### Using in NodeJS
>
> The `protocol-bufers` package offers an intuitive javascript API, so
>   you need not worry about low-level protocol concepts.
>
> This example demonstrates how you create a feed and start streaming:
>
> ```
> var protocol = require('hypercore-protocol')
> var stream = protocol()
>
> // open a feed specified by a 32 byte key
> var feed = stream.feed(Buffer('deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef'))
>
> feed.request({block: 42})
> feed.on('data', function (message) {
>   console.log(message) // contains message.index and message.value
> })
>
> stream.pipe(anotherStream).pipe(stream)
> ```

---

(**Note**: *The [hypercore](https://github.com/mafintosh/hypercore) protocol is one of the core specifications of the [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) ecosystem of modules for creating decentralized peer-to-peer application designs. I used their `.proto` file to demonstrate concepts*)